# looking for a (free) web hosting service that support flask, sqlite, and socketio

Tags: web-apps, python, web-services, sqlite, websocket

I built a simple web app with flask, socketio, and sqlite. 
Can anyone recommend a web hosting service that supports all three?

I tried Pythonanywhere but they do not support websockets. 
I also tried Heroku but they do not support sqlite.

Preferably the service is cheap (or free) and easy to use. 
Thanks!